# Proving that a set over a field is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Given: $S$ is a nonempty set, $K$ is a field. Let $C(S, K)$ denote the set of all functions ${f}\in\ C(S,K)$ such that ${f}(s) = 0 $ for all but a finite number of elements of $S$. Prove that $C(S, K)$ is a vector space.

OK. I was thinking about using the simple additive axioms that define vector spaces. One of those is that there exist two elements such that $x$ (which is some vector) added to zero equals $x$, or $x + 0 = x$.

Let $g(s)$ be an arbitrary function. $f + g = g$ when $f(s) = 0$. In addition, if we assume $g(s)$ to be in the space $C(S,K)$ and $f + g = g$ then both vectors are in the space $C(S,K)$ and are closed under addition.

Am I on the right track here? I feel like there's another step I need to have.

Comment: You define $\,C(S,K)\,$...by means of elements in $\,C(S,K)\,$ . That's not good.

Comment: Jesse, we encourage those who ask questions to accept one answer, if they find one to be helpful. You can only accept one answer per question asked, but you can upvote as many answers as you'd like. To accept an answer to your question, simply click on the $\large\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. You get two reputation points each time you accept an answer.

Comment: @amWhy sir,how to write a "right" sign in latex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very important construction in linear algebra. Given a set $S$ and a field $\Bbb F$ we can consider all functions $f : S \to \Bbb F$ such that $f(x) = 0$ unless on finetely many points of $S$. A function like that is said to have *finite support*. If we define addition and multiplication by scalar pointwise, then the set of all such functions form a vector space. All the axioms are trivially satisfied, the only one that may be tricky is the axiom of closure. Let us denote this set $F(S)$ (I'll change the notation for the set) and let's try to show that with these operations $F(S)$ is closed under linear combinations.

For that matter, consider $f_1, f_2 \in F(S)$ and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \Bbb F$. Then we want to show that we have  $\lambda_1 f_1 + \lambda_2 f_2 \in F(S)$. The idea is: there is a finite subset $S_1 \subset S$ such that $f_1$ is nonzero only there, and there is a finite set $S_2 \subset S$ such that $f_2$ is nonzero only there. The only place in $S$ where $\lambda_1 f_1 + \lambda_2 f_2$ can be nonzero is inside $S_1 \cup S_2$, because outside of it both functions are both zero. But this is a union of two finite sets, hence finite, and so the linear combination is also in $F(S)$.

Now, just to give you the notion of the importance of that, consider $\delta_a \in F(S)$ the function defined by:

$$\delta_a(x) = \begin{cases}1, & x=a \\ 0, & x\neq a\end{cases}$$

This function *indicates* wether the point $x$ is $a$ or not. If we consider $i : S \to F(S)$ given by $i(a) = \delta_a$ the set $i(S)$ will be a basis for $F(S)$ (try proving this). Since $\delta_a$ indicates wether a point is or not $a$, we may say that $\delta_a$ *represents* $a$ inside of $F(S)$. In that case, we will have a basis that *intuitively* we can think of as formed by the elements of $S$. So, when we have some arbitrary set, we can always construct a vector space from it that intuitively has the set $S$ as a basis, and we call this vector space the *free vector space* in terms of $S$ and denote it $F(S)$.

**Edit:** I've to define addition and multiplication by scalar pointwise. Well, this is a term used for the most common definition of these operations. We simply set:

$$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x) \quad \forall x \in S$$
$$(\lambda f)(x) = \lambda f(x) \quad \forall x \in S$$

Whenever some operation is defined like that we say that it is defined pointwise.

Comment: "If we define addition and multiplication by scalar pointwise, " -- um, what does that mean, exactly? Are you saying that we should define additionand multiplication by scalar the way it is in the axioms we were given? (One of which is that the scalars distribute, for instance)

Comment: I've added an edit about the meaning of defining operations pointwise.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

You first must define what the operations of sum and multiplication by a scalar are in that set $\,C(S,K)\,$ . These are pretty obvious, yet you **must** formally define them

Second, you must prove that under the definition above there's an element in $\,C(S,K)\,$ that serves as neutreal element of the sum.

Third, you must prove each element in $\,C(S,K)\,$ has an additive inverse.

Fourth, you must prove the corresponding axioms for multiplication by scalar.

Of the above, most is pretty simple and *almost* follows from the definitions.

Comment: are you saying that I should start with the axioms of multiplication and addition? What do you mean by defining them in that set, I thought we were trying to prove C(S,K) is a vector space. Also, when you describe a neutral element, what does that mean? I am new to this remember.

Comment: You need two sets to construct a vector space: the set that is going to be the vectors set, and the set that is *a field*. After this, you **must** define the operations on the first set so that it is an abelian group wrt that addition (closedness, neutral element, inverse...), and you **must** also define "product of a supposed vector with a scalar from the field". Then we can begin to work details!

Comment: What is an abelian group? This is my first assignment. The terms you are suing are making little sense to me right now. Pretend I am the dumbest student you have ever met, please! As I understand it I need to choose an arbitrary function, call it g, and that would be the set that is thefield? NOone of this makes any bloody sense to me now.

Comment: Forget that: the addition of vectors-to-be must fulfill $\;4\;$ (or sometimes $\;5\; $ , depending on the author) axioms, right? Well, whatever you define as addition it **must** fulfill all those axioms...

Comment: ok that is making a bit more sense to me now...

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Do you know that the set of *all* functions $S\to K$ is a vector space? Then most of the vector space axioms are also valid for $C(S,K)$.

If $f(x)\ne 0$ only for $x\in A$ and $g(x)\ne0$ only for $x\in B$ with $A,B$ finite, can you name a finite set such that $(f+g)(x)\ne0$ at most foer elements of that finite set?